Can anyone explain this meditation experience pls?
I recently did a two week mindfulness retreat (with focus on Primnordial Awareness) with beautiful conditions and I was grateful to have achieved a degree of concentration, which led to a few meditation experiences. I'm a little bit unclear about this one. Please may someone suggest either a text or a book to explain this please?
What occurred:
I used the gap between breaths to go into the groundless ground.
Experienced it as vibrations.
Saw multiple white circles of lights.
Then Tibetan Tankha type shapes.
Then had the circle of light at the centre of my forehead swivel (like it was a stage set).
Had the sense that my vision was turning around to look inwards.
Saw the shapes of my eyes and cavernous holes instead of my eyeballs.
This lasted for 2 seconds. Then the phenomenon faded, and I felt a snake like spiral of energy go down from my third eye.
Then it was back to 'normal'.
If anyone has any explanations, or has had similar experiences, and knows what it means for my practice, I'd be v grateful. With metta.

A nimitta is a light or other mental image that can appear in meditation. Ajahn Brahm said it's mental, not optical, not physical light, but that's how the mind perceives or represents it, because what it's experiencing is like light. He said "pabassara citta", "radiant mind", is the mind without the five hindrances and is incredibly bright. And he has said the five hindrances temporarily drop off during the jhana states. Other than that, they say all kinds of unusual things can happen in meditation, and not to get hung up on them.

thank you :) It happened on day 13 of the retreat and I have to say I did get (a bit) hung up on it - (now not so hung up anymore). And also - then that - I mean the getting hung up on - is what I need to work on! Thank you for your answer, with metta.

You're welcome. Yeah, the most common things I've heard of are visual perceptions and body sensations. Rapidly morphing faces of people you've never seen, or feeling like you're spinning, or your hands are far away, or you're bigger, etc. But I doubt a lot of that stuff would qualify as a nimitta, just weird perceptions. Maybe it's similar to what they say happens in a sensory deprivation tank; as if without sensory stimulation, the mind starts to make its own.

Yes i have had a few of this 'nimitta' experiences and this felt like one - you can literally feel yourself 'shift' into another gear - and it's great. But equally now, happy to rest in not-knowing what it was all about and just focus on the simple, basuc, profound practice of breath. Thank you :)

It sounds like it. Meditating all day for two weeks, you'd almost have to get some encouraging signs.
